# Error in SDTT for an array of hasOccupation objects using Roles: "hasOccupation is not a known valid target type for the hasOccupation property"

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Using JSON-LD syntax and the Schema.org vocab, per [Schema.org's `Occupation` example 4](https://pending.schema.org/Occupation#Person-gen-383), the following should be valid, but it is not.

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "sameAs": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Smith",
    "worksFor": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "McKinsey & Company",
        "url" : "http://www.mckinsey.com"
    },
    "hasOccupation": [ {
          "@type": "Role",
          "hasOccupation": {
            "name": "Management Consultant"
          },
          "startDate": "2016-04-21"
        }, {
          "@type": "Role",
          "hasOccupation": {
            "name": "Chief Strategic Officer"
          },
          "startDate": "2013-11-14",
          "endDate": "2016-03-22"
        }, {
          "@type": "Role",
          "hasOccupation": {
            "name": "Vice President of Sales"
          },
          "startDate": "2009-09-20",
          "endDate": "2013-10-14"
        }
    ]
}
```

Via Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool):

> **`hasOccupation`** is not a known valid target type for the `hasOccupation` property.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not providing the type of the `hasOccupation` value inside the `Role`. It expects an `Occupation` value.

So this

```json
"hasOccupation": {
  "name": "Management Consultant"
}
```

should becomes this

```json
"hasOccupation": {
  "@type": "Occupation",
  "name": "Management Consultant"
}
```

(Same for the other occurrences.)

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, although SDTT still gives and error. Try pasting this into SDTT https://pastebin.com/MxG2ULGr

Comment: @Orun: You are using the wrong quotation marks (the pastebin page highlights the affected lines in black instead of blue). If you fix this, SDTT will still report errors, but these are in a different category (missing properties → but they are not required by Schema.org, only required for getting a specific Google search result feature).

Comment: Wow, you're right. Can't believe I didn't see that. In the default monospace typeface in my editor didn't show the difference clearly. Thanks!